# setting global config values in karate

Tags: karate

What i am trying is that to set the global karate.config values from a feature file.

I have something very similar to this https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature

but i want to set the global config from the feature file or use the feature file in karate-config.js, then how do i access a variable from the feature file when calling using `karate.call`. And what is the recommended pathing for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a global variable, use `karate-config.js` as explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs

When using the `call` keyword, all global variables are inherited.

There is no recommended pathing. If you want you can create complex JSON for e.g. if you return `{ foo: { a: 1 } }` from `karate-config.js` you can use the value of `foo.a` anywhere in a feature file, for e.g:

```
* path 'blah', foo.a
```